# Deleting files with php - Drop down

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

Slightly different task this time round, I wish to delete files inside a specific directory with the click of a drop down option (Which calls the file name) and then followed this by a submit button click.

```
<?php
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
unlink($myFile);
?>
```

I am under the idea that the above code is what I need. However I make the "testFile.txt" is replaced with something along the lines of:

```
<?php $myFile = ?><html>Dropdown code here to list all files in directory</html><?php ;    unlink($myFile);
    ?>
```

I'm still editing and chopping the snippet so sorry if the response takes a while.

Edit: I was wondering if you could help me with creating it so that it is a drop down box of all the files uploaded into the directory /uploads/ so I can delete them without searching.

Thanks in advance everybody.

edit:

Ok, So after some help I have achieved this so far:

```
<?php
$path = "uploads/";
$handle = opendir($path);   

while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if (substr($file,0,1) != ".") {
    echo "<option value ='$file'></option>";
    }   
}
closedir($handle);  
?>
```

However this won't display the files in the options, I know im missing something here. I used your guys resources and:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: Sorry about that Mike, Can't believe I missed it out! Edited above. Thanks!

Comment: Well, break it down. First you need to get a listing of the files in the directory. Then you need to present it to the user. Then you need to figure out which one they chose (*cough*$_POST*cough*), then you need to delete it. You're basically asking us to write you an entire system here.

Comment: I'm sorry your under the impression I want you to write an entire system. I wasn't aiming towards that at all. Merely looking for advice on which direction to head.

Comment: Well, look at the rest of my post ;). Have a look at `readdir`.

Comment: You must do exactly as slugonamission wrote: break your complex problem in smaller problems that are easier to solve. So, where is your code to get a listing of the files in the directory? You must show us you tried something, and not ask questions like "I want that, give me all the code". [More information in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Like I said I'm sorry I gave the impression I was asking for the core code. If that was the case I would have used Google for those smaller problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way - it may not be perfect, I haven't tested it

dir will get you a listing of files in a directory, you can use that to populate an options list in PHP, and echo it out to your HTML page.

PHP:

```
$d = dir("myDirectory");

$files = array();
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    if($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') continue;
    $files[] = '<option value="'.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</option>';
}

$options = implode('',$files);
```

HTML:

```
<form...>
    <select name="file_delete"><?= $options;?></select>
    <input type="submit"... />
</form>
```

Then you can get the file from the $_POST or $_GET array after the user submits the form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Gareth, Thanks for the response. I'm unsure of whether I have this correct or not. I initially made the form in HTML thinking that was correct:

`<div id="DeleteFile">
Delete A Script:</div>
<br>

<form action="delete.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="DELETE_FILE" />

<select name="file_delete"><?= $options;?></select>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Delete File" />
</div>`

This is on my index page.

My Delete.php is the code you supplied But the myDirectory is "uploads/" I also added an echo.

Comment: The code I've posted is not quite complete - you need also to check the $_POST array to see if the form has been submitted, and in this case you have the filename you want to delete with the unlink($filname) command. The steps you need to follow are: List the files, construct the options list (the PHP code I provided), put the options list in a form on the page (pseudoHTML I gave), check the $_POST array in your PHP script, and if you find that the user has submitted, use the unlink. Basically, you need to add something like `if(isset($_POST['file_delete'])) { unlink($_POST['file_delete']); }`

Comment: Hey Gareth, I changed my original post which I believe may make it easier to understand and implement your code. It doesn't work in the drop down but if I echo the $File it does work.

I'l mess around with that for a bit and then get back to you. Thanks again Gareth :)

Comment: Hi - `echo "<option value='$file'>".$file."</option>";`. But this isn't really the problem. If you put your HTML in the same file as your PHP (You can "jump" in and out of PHP in the same file - see for example [How to mix HTML and PHP](http://www.howtoplaza.com/how-to-mix-html-and-php)) then the HTML code I gave you will successfully show you the list of options.

Comment: Hey Gareth, Got it working! :) Now all I have to do is embed the delete file option. Which I will attempt now. You have been very helpful. Kudos to you!